# get javascript array from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database

I am working on this google auth chat website everything has goon really smooth everything is basically done but the last thing that is to get the messages from a json database i can send messages to the json database but i cant get the array from the object here is my code:

index.js:

```
socket.on('load', () => {
    for (let i in data) {    
      socket.emit('add message', data[i]);
    }
  });
```

main.js(html file):

```
socket.emit('load');    
socket.on('add message', (text) => {
  let list = document.getElementById('list');    
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  list.appendChild(li)
});
```

Comment: and i am using a json database that is https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-db

Comment: oh sorry then ill edit the comment!

Comment: what is "data" variable? how do you get it? and what does it looks like? json string? can you post example of that variable content?

Comment: If I understand you unable to parse whatever data contains, right? Or can you point on exact error in your code?

Comment: ok heres the "data" variable let JsonDB = require('node-json-db');
let db = new JsonDB("messages", true, false);
let data = db.getData("/messages");

Comment: and yes i cant parse the data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A traditional json response from the node json DB is as follows:

```
data = {
test: {
    data1 : {
        messages : ['test','array']
    },
    data2 : 5
  }
}
```

From here, getting that messages array is simply to do this:

```
data.test.data1.messages
```

Example:
[image]